# PHP PUT Request

Tags: php

I have some documentation for an API system and it is telling me to send a PUT Request to a service URL, they have provided this:

```
PUT /domain/manage/renew/{domain_name}/{period}
```

along with the main URL to send the request to.

I thought to do this i would need to use `cURL` so I created the following:

```
$data = array("a" => $a);
$ch = curl_init($this->_serviceUrl . $id);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,http_build_query($data));

$response = curl_exec($ch);
if(!$response) {
    return false;
}
```

but they have also said:

```
The HTTP request header must contain the User, Hash and Encryption.

User: <username>
Hash: <authentication_hash>
Encryption: SHA-512
```

My question is:

1. How do i include this in the call?
2. and how do i sent both `{domain_name}` and `{period}` as per the url above?

Answer (score 0):

** UPDATED **

Send the headers like this:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [
    'User: '.$user, // change the variables to whatever you need, i.e. $this->user or whatever
    'Hash: '.$hash, // same here
    'Encryption: SHA-512'
]);

$response = curl_exec($ch);
if(!$response) {
    return false;
}
```

As for the URL, do something like this:

```
$ch = curl_init('http://www.example.com/domain/manage/renew/'.urlencode($domain_name).'/'.urlencode($period));
```

Comment: I will update the answer to tell you. Even though I could just say after your last `curl_setopt()` and before `curl_exec()`, but whatever...

Comment: ok, ive added those but it doesnt seem to be contacting the API platform - i cannot see the request coming in

Comment: Are you sure you have the right variables for the URL and headers? Maybe you can echo them all to see if the info is right. If everything's alright, maybe  you can show me the error message? Sometimes it depends on the API you're using, I don't know what you're doing, but usually the response array will come with an error element you can check.

Comment: doing a `var_dump($response)` returns `bool(false)` - the variables are correct

Comment: @user6486397 ok, then does the API say anything about sending data as JSON?

Comment: aha - it does say this **All REST API methods use JSON in the request and response bodies. The JSON format for different API objects is provided in the Types section. Fields marked as required must be specified when creating and updating objects. Optional fields can be specified on create and update, but the request will succeed whether or not they are provided.**

Comment: Then, I will update my answer because you need to use `json_encode()` instead of `http_build_query()`. This will encode your `$data` array into JSON and send the appropriate data that the API is looking for.

Comment: In other words, you were now sending unrecognizable data for the API.

Comment: ok - i see now. there isnt anything actually in the `$data` variable - that was just an example i found on the internet but i suppose i shouldn't have included it in my question! :) - all i need is to send the PUT request with the 2 variables in the URL but they want me to send it using JSON

Comment: Well, in that case all you need to do is to add another Header just like I told you to add the other ones with the following string: "Content-Type: application/json". That will tell the API that everything is sent as JSON.